# how to use in statement in where clause using entitydatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to full dropdownlist from entitydatasource but >>>

i have a problem

```
CommandText="SELECT d.[firstName] FROM DentistEntities.Doctors AS d WHERE d.[id] IN (SELECT s.[doctorID] FROM DentistEntities.DoctorsOfSections AS s WHERE s.[sectionID] = 2)"
```

this my asp code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="doctorlist" runat="server" Width="172px" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" DataTextField="firstName" DataValueField="firstName">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=DentistEntities" DefaultContainerName="DentistEntities" CommandText="SELECT d.[firstName] FROM DentistEntities.Doctors AS d WHERE d.[id] IN (SELECT s.[doctorID] FROM DentistEntities.DoctorsOfSections AS s WHERE s.[sectionID] = 2)">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

but when i compile i had this error

> The element type 'Edm.Int32' and the CollectionType 'Transient.collection[Transient.rowtype(doctorID,Edm.Int32(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=))]' are not compatible. The IN expression only supports entity, scalar and reference types.  Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 69.

plz any help

thank you

Comment: Does the column `Doctors.id` allow `null` and does the column `DoctorsOfSections.doctorID` allow `null`? From the message it looks like there is a mismatch and you may need to use COALESCE in your SQL statement.

Comment: COALESCE' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function. Near simple identifier,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone having the same problem can try this (note the 'VALUE' keyword in the subselect):

```
CommandText="SELECT d.[firstName] FROM DentistEntities.Doctors AS d WHERE d.[id] IN (SELECT VALUE s.[doctorID] FROM DentistEntities.DoctorsOfSections AS s WHERE s.[sectionID] = 2)"
```